# Mapping single list to various tables depending on the class of its records

Tags: java, hibernate, polymorphism, hibernate-mapping

Suppose we have class A which has a list of class B objects (`List<B>` **listOfBs**). In database design this means that table representing class B should have a foreign key referring to rows of table representing class A. Now, class B is a superclass of class C, D and E.
My hibernate mapping file of class A is the following and works fine for storing class A entries to the database and also cascading at the same time multiple entries of class B that are contained in the list of class A.

**Class A Hibernate Mapping File:**

```
<hibernate-mapping package="..."> 
    <class name="A" table="table_of_A"> 
        <id name="key" column="A_ID"> 
            <generator class="native"/> 
        </id> 
        <property name="...." type="long"/>
        <property name="...." type="string"/>
        <list name="listOfBs" access="field" cascade="all">
               <key column="A_ID" not-null="true" />
               <list-index column="idx"/>
               <one-to-many class="B"/>
        </list>
    </class> 
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am trying to figure out what I should include to the hibernate file shown above so I can store in the database the **listOfBs** which might containts objects of class C, D and E and therefore each of the object on the **listOfBs** should go to the appropriate table in the database.
Note that I am using the **table per concrete class with implicit polymorphism strategy** for mapping inheritance on hibernate.

Any help would really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did a more detailed description on the following link: [Detailed Description Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325742/hibernate-mapping-with-one-to-many-polymorphic-relationship)

Answer (score 0):

So here you are using table per concrete class and being B as a super-class u can use Generalization functionality provided by the hibernate.

In hibernate there are three different ways by which inheritance can be represented.

**1. Table per class hierarchy**

**2. Table per subclass**

**3. Table per concrete class**

Since you are using `table per concrete` class you will need to change class B mapping as per below

```
<class name="B">
<id name="id" column="ID">
    <generator class="sequence"/>
</id>
<property name="name" column="NAME"/>
<union-subclass name="C" table="C">
    <property name="${properties}" column="collumns"/>
</union-subclass>
<union-subclass name="D" table="D">
    <property name="${properties}" column="collumns"/>
</union-subclass>
<union-subclass name="E" table="E">
    <property name="${properties}" column="collumns"/>
</union-subclass>
</class>
```

[This](http://v4forums.wordpress.com/2008/12/27/implicit-explicit-polymorphism-in-hibernate/) is the reference link,

Comment: I tried that myself too and the `<generator class="sequence">` gives me "org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not get next sequence value" error. I actually used `<generator class="sequence">
    <param name="sequence">B_id_seq</param>
   </generator>`. I am using HSQL DB if that helps.

Comment: try using 'native' or 'increment'.

Comment: 'native' does not work with `union-subclass`. Increment gives me `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not fetch initial value for increment generator`.